# How does work the spark application listens to port?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Can I run the program, listens at the port in the cluster? 
I want to write an application that accepts http requests and performs some calculation using spark

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking here? I guess English isn't your first language, but "car" isn't the right term. Can you add more detail so we can try to work out what you are asking?

Comment: This thread looks relevant: http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Calling-spark-from-a-java-web-application-td20007.html

Comment: Also this https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can run any code you want on driver node. You can use, for example, [spray.io](http://spray.io/) http server and connect to spark actor system:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkEnv
implicit val system = SparkEnv.get.actorSystem
```

But there is no way to execute arbitrary code on workers. Workers run only  code blocks inside RDD's map-reduce functions.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to understand your English, but, if I understood you correctly you are looking for something like [Spark-JobServer](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver)